# Why does an element of an array constructed with `readarray` gain a fictitious `\n` when it's enclosed in double quotes?

Tags: bash, array, newlines

I found a behavior of `readarray` that I can't get to the bottom of myself.

The following code:

```
readarray array < <(echo -e "Jenny\nJane\nJessica")

echo "* Not enclosed:"
for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++)); do
    echo ${array[$i]}
done

echo "* Enclosed:"
for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++)); do
    echo "${array[$i]}"
done
```

Produces the following output:

```
* Not enclosed:
Jenny
Jane
Jessica
* Enclosed:
Jenny

Jane

Jessica
```

Why exactly do elements become spaced out when they are enclosed with `" "` like this?
Even if I replaced `echo "${array[$i]}"` with a variable like this:

```
foo=${array[$i]}
echo "$foo"
```

The output still becomes spaced out.
But note that if I declared the array in the usual fashion `array=("Jenny" "Jane "Jessica")` no spacing is inserted regardless of quotes.

Reason why this is causing problems because I'm looping through an array and need to use the element inside a sentence and echo it. For example:

```
readarray array < <(echo -e "Jenny\nJane\nJessica")
for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++)); do
    echo "Hello, ${array[$i]}!"
done
```

However `${array[$i]}` is in-between `" "` so `\n` gets inserted and the output becomes:

```
Hello, Jenny
!
Hello, Jane
!
Hello, Jessica
!
```

Comment: Does adding `-t` to readarray help?

Comment: In other words, there IS an entirely real newline in each array element value, but `echo ${ary[sub]}` or `echo $var` without quotes (and without fiddled IFS) _removes_ any leading, trailing, or consecutive whitespace, regardless of where it came from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the readarray doesn't remove the delimiter (newline by default) unless it is called with the `-t` option.

Using the simpler `declare -p var` to print array values, look at this:

```
$ readarray array < <(echo -e "Jenny\nJane\nJessica")
$ declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]=$'Jenny\n' [1]=$'Jane\n' [2]=$'Jessica\n')
```

You can see the trailing newlines for each element.

While this:

```
$ readarray -t array < <(echo -e "Jenny\nJane\nJessica")
$ declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]="Jenny" [1]="Jane" [2]="Jessica")
```

does not have trailing newlines.

The use of an unquoted variable expansion is just a bad idea, just don't.

Comment: "The use of an unquoted variable expansion is just a bad idea, just don't." Sure. But when using "=~" to match against a regular expression, quotes are forbidden on the regex (right hand) side of the operator. If you're reading an array of regexes from a file, you need this. I think. Unless I'm missing the obvious, which I usually do....